# How to use WriteableBitmap

Tags: c#

I'm trying my best to follow this tutorial here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2013/06/13/tutorial-series-learning-how-to-write-a-3d-soft-engine-from-scratch-in-c-typescript-or-javascript.aspx and have come across a problem that I can't seem to fix, I'm trying to create a WriteableBitmap instance like "private WriteableBitmap bmp;" and it says the type/namespace could not be found... I think it's because the namespace "using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;" is also saying it can't be found... am I supposed to be adding a reference to the project? I have no clue >_<

Comment: What kind of project did you create? The tutorial specifically says it's starting with a C# WinRT/XAML Windows Store app, which should give you all the references you need to use WriteableBitmap.

Comment: Okay, really stupid question but how do I make a WinRT/XAML Windows Store app? When I make a new project all I see is windows form app, WPF app, console app and class library...

Comment: Side note: Make sure you have Win8 - check requirements of [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx), and lates VS (if using Express - make sure to get one for WinRT apps).

Comment: I use Windows 7, do I need to have Windows 8 to create a WinRT/XAML Windows Store app?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the article you linked to in your question, you need Windows 8 to create Windows Store apps.